# Copy of the file /bin/sh not executing as expected

Tags: permissions, root, chmod, chown

I have Ubuntu installed in VirtualBox on Windows 10 only for two days, so this may sound silly. I have a reasoning problem somewhere and I don't know why. I copied the file `/bin/sh` to my own directory, so, theoretically, I have become the owner of the copy. I used the command `chmod` to set the `suid` bit and `chown` to set the owner to root. So, if the copy of the file is executed I should have a privilege of being the root. However this doesn't happen. Where am I wrong?

Comment: What happens specifically?

Comment: @Eduardo Cola : Actually, I tried to do it again but I get stuck at `chmod u+s sh` it says: `cannot operate on dangling symlink 'sh'`

Answer (score 0):

You copied a symbolic link which is just a pointer to the real binary. Use `ls -alh /bin/sh` to show which binary is linked.